# Transforming glsl 150 to 120

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a couple of examples that I want to run on my PC. The problem is that they're written with glsl target 150 and my PC only supports version 120. I'm pretty sure that the program itself is simple enough not to require any extended functionality of OpenGL 3.1. I have found some information on what steps should be taken to transform glsl(f.e. changing in to attribute, out to varying) but it's still not compiling(is it actually possible to somehow get a meaningful error message out of this?).

original .vert

```
#version 150
in  vec2 in_Position;
in  vec3 in_Color;
out vec3 ex_Color;
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x, in_Position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

original .frag

```
#version 150
precision highp float;

in  vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);
}
```

changed .vert

```
#version 120 
attribute  vec2 in_Position; 
attribute  vec3 in_Color; 
varying vec3 ex_Color; 
void main(void) { 
    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x, in_Position.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
    ex_Color = in_Color; 
}
```

changed .frag

```
#version 120 
precision highp float; 

attribute  vec3 ex_Color; 

void main(void) { 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0); 
}
```

So can anyone spot a problem here?

Comment: Do you have any error message you could quote in your question, whether it is meaningful to you or not?

Comment: "*is it actually possible to somehow get a meaningful error message out of this?*" [Did you get the infolog?](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Object#Error_handling)

Comment: Initially I just had a message that said that I was linking with an uncompiled shader and nothing else.

Comment: The GLSL 150 shaders shouldn't compile. gl_Position, gl_FragColor are removed from >= 150. And the gl_ prefix is reserved and should throw errors if you try and use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the compile/link error messages, you need to use the commands `glGetShaderInfoLog` for shaders, and `glGetProgramInfoLog` for programs.

These will tell you what your particular errors are.

Just taking a stab at what the error might be, you're declaring an `attribute` input in the fragment shader, which I believe should be a `varying`. Attributes are for data->vertex shader, and varyings are for vertex shader -> fragment shader.

The glsl 120 spec also mentions that precision qualifier is "reserved for future use", so it may not be applicable to version 120. You can probably leave it out.

But you should still get familiar with the infolog functions regardless, you'll definitely need them eventually.

Comment: Thanks. You spotted both of my problems. One thing I don't get is how this attribute and varying works when we are just rewriting everything for an older version. I got the idea that out > varying and in > attribute. Was the initial code wrong in this case or am I missing something else?

Comment: *I got the idea that out > varying and in > attribute.*, This is true for vertex shader, not for fragment shader. Varying is input to fragment shader.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the compile errors by retrieving the "info log":

```
GLuint nVertexShader, nPixelShader;   // handles to objects
GLint  vertCompiled, fragCompiled;    // status values
GLint  linked;

glCompileShader(nVertexShader);
glGetShaderiv(nVertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &vertCompiled);
```

if vertCompiled (or fragCompile) == 0, do this to see why:

```
int infologLength = 0;
int charsWritten  = 0;

glGetShaderiv(nVertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);

if (infologLength > 0)
{
    GLchar* infoLog = (GLchar *)malloc(infologLength);
    if (infoLog == NULL)
    {
        printf( "ERROR: Could not allocate InfoLog buffer");
        exit(1);
    }
    glGetShaderInfoLog(nVertexShader, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
    printf( "Shader InfoLog:\n%s", infoLog );
    free(infoLog);
}
```

You can do the same with linking, just check for linked == 0 and retrieve the log as above:

```
glLinkProgram(m_nProgram);
glGetProgramiv(m_nProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
precision highp float;
```

That is not legal in GLSL 1.20. I don't even know why it was put in the 1.50 shader anyway, since the precision qualifiers only do useful things in GLSL ***ES***, and you can't share 1.50 shaders with GLSL ES.